# Grails static resource unacessible from root

Tags: grails, grails-2.2, static-resource

I have a file named

favicon.ico

in the web-app folder (grails 2.2.1).

My app is configured to run as root app /

If I open the url

```
http://mydomain/favicon.ico
```

I got a not 404 not found.

If I try to move the file in any subfolder it works. For example if I move it to

```
web-app/test/favicon.ico
```

and I open

```
http://mydomain/favicon.ico
```

the file is correctly served.

The problem is the same if I run the app with grails run-app

Answer (score 1):

You can configure in the Config.groovy to process resources in / like this:
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/*','/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']

`http://mydomain/favicon.ico`

will get a 302 to:
`http://mydomain/static/favicon.ico`

That should work, but I think its better to move your ico to /images

Comment: Thankyou. I have solved adding favicon.ico to urlmapping exclude list. Your solution may work but I don't think that respond to every favicon request with a 302 is a smart solution.
/favicon.ico is the standar browser detected location for favicon. If you don't want to use that location you have to redefine it with a metatag inside the page and I don't see any reason to do do it.